# Use of AppKit image template constant yields null

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsimage

The documentation for `NSImage` lists a lot of standard images that should be readily available using `+[NSImage imageNamed:]`.  They are listed in the [`NSImage` class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

I keep getting `(null)` when I try to load the following, however, and that result is not limited to `NSImageNameSmartBadgeTemplate`.  The code works as expected when given the name of an image in my program's bundle.  Any thoughts?

```
NSString *filterIconName = @"NSImageNameSmartBadgeTemplate";
_icon = [NSImage imageNamed:filterIconName];
NSLog(@"icon = %@", _icon);
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that this is under 10.7

Answer (score 6):

The *contents* of the string identifying the image aren't necessarily the same as the *name* of the string. You want to do your assignment using the *name*, like this:

```
NSString *filterIconName = NSImageNameSmartBadgeTemplate;
```

Or just use the name directly:

```
[NSImage imageNamed:NSImageNameSmartBadgeTemplate]
```

You can only see the declaration of the name in the public header: `extern NSString * const PeanutButter`. When Apple defines the string in another file, the value could be anything:

```
NSString * const PeanutButter = @"Jelly";
```

Apple can also change the value of the string, should they deem it necessary, and your code will continue to work as long as you only refer to the name.